# How to mock useNavigation hook in react-navigation 5.0 for jest test?

Tags: jestjs, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v5

i want to mock useNavigation hook used inside my functional component. Any workaround how to mock it using jest?

```
import React from 'react';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const { navigate } = useNavigation();

  const navigateToScreen = () => {
    navigate('myScreen', { param1: 'data1', param2: 'data2' })
  }

  return (<TouchableOpacity onPress={navigateToScreen}>
       Go To Screen
     </TouchableOpacity>)
}
```

how to test params being passed in navigate function ?

Comment: Please provide minimal, complete the code under test

Comment: @slideshowp2 updated with code and description

Answer (score 54):

I know I'm late, but I had the issue where I needed to know know when the navigate function was called.

For it, I mocked the function the following way, so the `mockedNavigate` would be a jest function that i could use later if i needed to test if the function was actually called:

```js
const mockedNavigate = jest.fn();

jest.mock('@react-navigation/native', () => {
  const actualNav = jest.requireActual('@react-navigation/native');
  return {
    ...actualNav,
    useNavigation: () => ({
      navigate: mockedNavigate,
    }),
  };
});
```

This allowed me to use this later and I would know if I could navigate properly in my application:

```js
expect(mockedNavigate).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How to mock this navigation V5. with Provider?

Comment: In order for this to work I had to declare this at the root of the test file (not in a `describe` or `it/test` statement

Comment: It's also possible to put this in your jest setup file and export `mockedNavigate`. Then in each test file you only have to import that mock function, in my case: `import { mockedNavigate } from '../../../../test/setup'`.

Comment: It's also possible to put this in your jest setup file and export `mockedNavigate`. Then in each test file you only have to import that mock function, in my case: `import { mockedNavigate } from '../../../../test/setup'`.

Comment: Thanks @blwinters for commenting this. I've been thinking how I can access the mocked function, eventually we only need export it for access haha

Answer (score 6):

Another quite late solution that is a bit cleaner than the previously suggested ones.

```
const mockedNavigate = jest.fn();

jest.mock('@react-navigation/native', () => (
  { useNavigation: () => ({ navigate: mockedNavigate }) }));
```

This does not include any other functionality of the navigation object but it will allow you to test in the following way:

```
expect(mockedNavigate).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

Or with `expect.toHaveBeenCalledWith()` ([here](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tohavebeencalledwitharg1-arg2-)) if more applicable in your specific situation.

Answer (score 5):

```
jest.mock("@react-navigation/native", () => {
  const actualNav = jest.requireActual("@react-navigation/native")
  return {
    ...actualNav,
    useFocusEffect: () => jest.fn(),
    useNavigation: () => ({
      navigate: jest.fn(),
    }),
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you edit this to include some explanation of what you're doing and why it's a good solution to the problem? That will help the OP and any future readers understand not just _what_ to do, but also _why_.

Comment: it will also helpful for me if you add some example here.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a solution for a *mock* of `useNavigation`, but I found this helpful to achieve my own intent (spying), and it looks like it would achieve the OP's intent (expecting on calls)

```
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/routers';
jest.spyOn(CommonActions, 'navigate');
```

This seems to be where the actions that surface out of the `useNavigation` hook are defined, too. I was unsuccessful to create a mock on this, but the spy works excellently.

#### Caveat

I'm using react-navigation 6.

I am calling `render` with a `NavigationContainer` thus I am not mocking anything in react-navigation, hence I can spy. If you don't do that, and you're looking to truly mock navigation, this won't work.

FWIW, I would recommend trying this approach first, as you can then allow much more of your code to be tested properly, as it would get used.
e.g. For my `CaptureLocationScreen` which is in a `Stack` inside a modal.

```
render(
  <NavigationContainer>
    <RootStack.Navigator>
      <RootStack.Group screenOptions={{ presentation: 'modal', }}>
        <RootStack.Screen
          name="CaptureLocation"
          component={CaptureLocationScreen}
          options={({ navigation }: RootStackScreenProps<'CaptureLocation'>) => ({
            headerTitle: 'Add new location',
            headerLeft: () => (<CloseButton onPressed={navigation.goBack} />),
            headerRight: () => (<AcceptButton />)
          })} />
      </RootStack.Group>
    </RootStack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>);
```

### References

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions/